# Is this a false positive by Avast?

Tags: virus

Avast keeps detecting the rootkit Win32:Evo-gen. I select to delete it, but when I restart the computer the message pops up again. The location is `C:\Program Files(x86)\ASUS\AsusFanControlService\1.00.17\AsusFanControlService.exe` this somewhat makes sense because I do have an Asus motherboard. Should I choose "ignore" and remember the selection or is it likely I do have a virus that is resisting deletion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: Upload the file to [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/) if avast is the only one who reports it as a virus then it is a false positive, if a lot report it you should look in to it more.

Comment: Although this case screams false positive, upload the file to virustotal to be sure..

Comment: Oops read Scott's comment after posting mine... :P

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes, it looks like this is a false positive.

Long answer: A cursory Google search turns up dozens of similar results for "Avast Asus Fan Control false positive". Very likely, Avast's heuristics are detecting some activity by the fan control service (like direct hardware access) as a "back door".

I wouldn't worry about it. Change to a better antivirus offering like Kaspersky, or F-Secure.

Comment: The one thing Avast has that I can find no equivalent in any other antivirus is it's SafeZone, if it wasn't fort that I would've dumped avast along time ago